# Use LINQ without putting data in memory

Tags: c#, linq, file

I have a large number of records of data in a binary file, and I want to search for something in it. Is there any way that could I use LINQ statement on the file data without putting all the data in memory (like`List<T>`)?

I have this methods that use `List<Book>` :

```
private Book Read(long position)
{
    Book book;
    using (Stream st = File.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "library.majid", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        st.Position = position;
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(st))
        {
            if (!reader.ReadBoolean())
                return null;
            book = new Book()
            {
                Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
                Name = reader.ReadString(),
                Dewey = reader.ReadString()
            };
            try
            {
                book.Subject = reader.ReadString();
                book.RegDate = reader.ReadInt32();
                book.PubDate = reader.ReadInt32();
            }
                catch (EndOfStreamException) { }
            }
        }
        return book;
    }
        private List<Book> getAll( int recordLength = 100)//sorted results by Id!!
    {
        long Len;
        using (Stream st = File.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "library.majid", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Len = st.Length;
        }
        List<Book> res = new List<Book>();
        Book ReadedBook = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < Len/100; i++)
        {
            ReadedBook = Read(i * 100);
            if (ReadedBook != null)
                res.Add(ReadedBook);
        }
        res.Sort((x, y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Consider showing your file structure and some code that shows your current effort.

Comment: What advantage does not putting data into memory give you?

Comment: you can't use linq to objects without them being in memory. you could write a custom query provider.

Comment: @Brad if system memory be small system will be slow

Comment: @majidgeek I suggest you searching for `BinarySerialization`.

Comment: @majidgeek isn't letting the OS manage that sort of thing going to be better performance though? Having some data in memory seems faster than forcing all data to be read from disk.

Comment: @Brad If you have a large file it's quite reasonable to be in the situation where you don't have enough physical RAM to store all of the data that you need.  If you're forced to swap data out to disk, or end up running out of virtual memory in your program, then it becomes *very* important to be able to stream the data instead of loading it all into memory at once.

Comment: You wil need to create a custom `IQueryProvider`, imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a text file, you can use `File.ReadLines(filename)` which returns `IEnumerable<string>`, without loading the file to memory.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

For ex;

```
var count = File.ReadLines(somefile)
                .Where(line => line.StartsWith("something"))
                .Count();
```

**EDIT**

> *what If it be a binary file?*

Then you can write a method similar to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Book> ReadBooks(string filename)
{
    using (var f = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(f))
        {
            Book b = new Book();
            //.....
            yield return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what If it be a binary file?

Comment: @majidgeek Like in your code. Read from binary file(ReadInt32, ReadString etc.) and assign properties of `Book`

Comment: @majidgeek nowhere. just assign properties at `//.....` that's all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to search for some data you can keep a similar implementation of your method `getAll`, pass some parameters to perform the search and return a List (or `IEnumerable<T>`). This way you only keep in memory the result items.

Your `Read` method will not keep elements in memory (only on the method scope).

By the way you could pass the stream reader to your `Read` method so you will not create a new reader for each iteration. The stream "cursor" will be keep the position of the last chunk of read data.